# UITableView: delete section controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there a way to add delete controls, like in UITableViewCell, on a table section? I see two ways:

- Use table cell instead of sections.
- Write own UIView section class, which will show delete controls.

Regarding the first way - as I think, it could be an easiest way in my situation.

The second way may be better from the implementation point of view, but it will take more time.

May be I missed another way? Any suggestions?

Comment: You want that the user will be able to delete all the cells inside one section by tapping the section's header or some button that is located in the section header?

Comment: yeah, I think he wants to do so

Comment: Button inside a section, which will allow user to remove whole section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see is to provide your UITableViewController Delegate or Subclass with the method called:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

This gives you the power to display any kind of UIView as a section-header. within this view you can place controls that enable the user to delete sections.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Yep, this what the second option is in my post.

Comment: From my point of view this is the most proper approach to solve your problem.